# ERR_CACHE_MISS in Codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

Why does my web app keep showing error `ERR_CACHE_MISS` when editing an image but without image is fine? I am using Codeigniter.

#### Controller:

```
function edit_produk($id) {
    $content['module'] = 'produk' ;
    $content['view'] = 'edit_produk_';
    $content['id'] = $id;
    $this->template->index($content);
}
function edit_produk_() {
    $content['status'] = "";
    if(isset($_POST['save'])) {
        $unique  = rand(0000000,999999999);
        $unique2 = rand(0000000,999999999);
        if($_FILES['gambar']['name'] == ''){
        $gambar  = '';          
        }
        else {
        $gambar  = $unique.'.jpg';      
        }
        if($_FILES['gambar2']['name'] == ''){
        $gambar2     = '';          
        }
        else {
        $gambar2 = $unique2.'.jpg'; 
}

    if($_FILES['gambar']['name'] != ''){


            if($_POST['default'] == "") {


                $config['upload_path'] = './gambar/';                        
                $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png|jpeg|gif';
                $config['max_size'] = '100000'; // 0 = no file size limit
                $config['file_name'] = $gambar;
                $config['overwrite'] = false;
                $this->upload->initialize($config);
                $this->load->library('upload', $config);
                $this->upload->do_upload('gambar');

            }

    else  {

            unlink('./gambar/'.$_POST['default']);
            $config['upload_path'] = "./gambar";
            $config['max_size'] = '100000'; // 0 = no file size limit
            $config['file_name'] = $gambar;
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
            $this->upload->initialize($config);

        if (!$this->upload->do_upload('gambar'))    {
        echo $this->upload->display_errors('<p>', '</p>');
        $gambar = "";
        }
    }   
    }

    if($_FILES['gambar2']['name'] != ''){


            if($_POST['default2'] == "") {


                $config['upload_path'] = './gambar/';                        
                $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png|jpeg|gif';
                $config['max_size'] = '100000'; // 0 = no file size limit
                $config['file_name'] = $gambar2;
                $config['overwrite'] = false;
                $this->upload->initialize($config);
                $this->load->library('upload', $config);
                 $this->upload->do_upload('gambar2');

            }

    else  {

            unlink('./gambar/'.$_POST['default2']);
            $config['upload_path'] = "./gambar";
            $config['max_size'] = '100000'; // 0 = no file size limit
            $config['file_name'] = $gambar2;
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
            $this->upload->initialize($config);

            $this->upload->do_upload('gambar2');


    }   
    }
$kirim = $this->mdl_produk->edit_produk($gambar,$gambar2);
$content['status'] = $kirim;


    } 
    else {

    $this->load->view('edit_produk',$content);


}
}
```

#### Model:

```
function input_produk($nama,$nama2) {
$data['nama']    = $_POST['nama'];
$data['keterangan']    =$_POST['keterangan'];
$data['harga']       = $_POST['harga'];
$data['kategori']    = $_POST['kategori'];
$data['gambar']   = $nama;
$data['gambar2']  = $nama2;
$query = $this->db->insert('produk', $data);
    if($query) {
    $kirim = "<div class='alert alert-success alert-dismissable'><button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;</button>Berhasil Input produk</div>";
    }
    else {
    $kirim ="<div class='alert alert-danger alert-dismissable'><button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;</button>Gagal Input produk Silahkan Kontak produkistrator</div>";
    }   
    return $kirim;
}

function edit_produk($nama,$nama2) {
$data['nama']       = $_POST['nama'];
$data['id']               = $_POST['id'];
$data['keterangan']   = $_POST['keterangan'];
$data['harga']   = $_POST['harga'];
$data['kategori']   = $_POST['kategori'];
if($nama ==  "") {
$data['gambar']           = $_POST['default'];
}
else {
$data['gambar']           = $nama;
}
if($nama2 == "") {
$data['gambar2']          = $_POST['default2'];
}
else {
$data['gambar2']          = $nama2;
}


$query = $this->db->query('UPDATE `produk` SET `nama` = "'.$data['nama'].'", keterangan = "'.$data['keterangan'].'", gambar = "'.$data['gambar'].'", gambar2 = "'.$data['gambar2'].'" , harga = "'.$data['harga'].'" , kategori = "'.$data['kategori'].'" WHERE id = "'.$data['id'].'" ');
    if($query) {
    $kirim = "<div class='alert alert-success alert-dismissable'><button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;</button>Berhasil Edit produk Untuk Kembali Mengedit Silahkan Klik tombol Kembali Dan Pilih Data Yang Akan Di Edit</div>";
    }
    else {
    $kirim ="<div class='alert alert-danger alert-dismissable'><button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;</button>Gagal Edit produk Silahkan Kontak produkistrator</div>";
    }   
    return $kirim;

}}
```

Normally if editing is successful, it will show something [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zR7fu.png).

However, if I try editing an image, the edit is successful but in browser is showing `ERR_CACHE_MISS` [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/peVHq.png).

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved

I Try To Recode And It Works
I Don't know why

Thank you